# Coordinate layout Overlapping container

Tags: android

I am using this layout to load the fragments in side it but when i run that on device it gives look like this.

[image]

Below is my code.Any suggest why framelayout is overlapping coordinate layout.
Thanks for help :)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:elevation="7dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/cl_root_inner_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/tool_rl"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:titleTextColor="@color/white"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/buttonsview"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/btnBack"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:padding="@dimen/x10"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_back" />


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/fragtitle"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:text="@string/select_district"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:visibility="invisible" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btnPost"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/x10"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:text="@string/post"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:theme="@style/blue_button" />

                </RelativeLayout>


            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:background="@color/orange"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a xml using coordinator layout, I think this will help you

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.software.products.ui.activity.ToolbarUsedActivity"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <--!just use toolbar here-->

        <com.software.android.view.ddToolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <include layout="@layout/content_main2" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```